# function postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I am analyzing a function in PostgreSQL and I come across a function that takes two parameters but I did not understand how they called, on the second parameter

the function is the following:

```
getdimensionuserid(integer, text)
```

it's called in the following way:

```
getdimensionuserid(18 , ?::text)
```

I do not understand how they specify the second parameter. the `?::text`

Comment: are you using perl?

Answer (score 0):

That's casting syntax,

```
getdimensionuserid(18 , ?::text)
```

Is the same as

```
getdimensionuserid(18 , CAST(? AS text) )
```

That's usually not required and a bad idea though.

1. If the type on the table can be implicitly converted to-from text then it does nothing,
2. all data to-from the database gets serialized as text. LibPQ doesn't even support a binary mode.

Comment: and the question mark what is its meaning

Comment: @hakim it's a placeholder in many languages for a value `stmt = dbh.query("select x from table where y = ?); result = stmt.execute(5)`